# Android TTS add languages

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I would like to develop an app that uses TTS for many languages. The problem is that only few languages come with specific devices, depending on the country I suppose (I'm talking about PICO). Is there a way to use a TTS engin embedded in my apk or find somewhere online the missing PICO files and put them in the apk... or any other solution to support languages but present in the device by default?

Answer (score 4):

Read this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

There is an intent (action - ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA) which automatically will download required languages.

Also, I believe you can do two things:

a) Implement your own service based on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService.html).

b) You can load some custom files using API - addEarcon(String earcon, String filename)
 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I don't see how to use this for my purpose. If I check ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA I suppose the application will download the default locale, I don't see how to specify it... supposing I want the app to download Czech on a Portuguese device.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA works. I get impression that it will download multiple languages. You should try it. You can specify later on which language you want to use using API:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setLanguage(java.util.Locale)

Comment: I suspect there's no way to get extra languages. From what I could do, by forcing the installation, the only free languages are EN, FR, ES, DE, IT

Comment: Try to look on TextToSpeechService then. I didn't find too much info on it, but it has interface onIsLanguageAvailable(String, String, String). I guess it's used to extend TTS. BTW. Here is the link with some implementation of TextToSpeechService: http://android.cocoaone.com/resources/samples/TtsEngine/src/com/example/android/ttsengine/RobotSpeakTtsService.html