# How to download locale for TTS (Text-to-speech) in Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to let the TTS engine to read me out the text in my app. By default, the *Locale* and *language* are based on device info (in my case it is `en_US`, where `en` is the language and `US` is the country).

However, if I want to listen to the voice in `en_AU` I need to do the following go to

> Device ->  Settings ->  Language and Input ->  Settings for the
>   Preferred Engine (in my case Google TTS) -> Install voice data -> English (Australia)

I would like to know if it is possible to install the necessary *Voice Data* directly from my Android app

**EDIT :**  I think the question is not well put. The app I am developing will display me a list of voices (not all the voices that are available with TTS Engine) I can use with my TTS engine (say `en_US`, `en_IN`, `en_UK`, `en_AU`). Since my device's default language is set to `en_US`, the `en_US` voice comes pre-installed. I am trying to find a way to install the remaining voices (`en_IN`, `en_UK`, `en_AU`) automatically right from my app instead of following the steps mentioned above.

Comment: You cannot do this. You'll need to direct the user to the Android Text to Speech Settings and from there they'll need to manually install any additional language files. It would be a security issue otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TTS add languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251628/android-tts-add-languages)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();

Comment: Your code seems to find me the ISO code from the sim. I get that. But, I think the question is not well put. The app I am developing will display me a list of voices I can use with my TTS engine (say en_US, en_IN, en_UK, en_AU). Since my device's default language is set to en_US, the en_US voice comes pre-installed. I am trying to find a way to install the remaining voices automatically right from my device instead of following the steps mentioned in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to get about the languages available/downloaded. I get this from the flutter documentation (that's what I'm using to program):

isLanguageInstalled is checking for KEY_FEATURE_NOT_INSTALLED:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine#KEY_FEATURE_NOT_INSTALLED

isLanguageAvailable:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#isLanguageAvailable(java.util.Locale)

From the documentation:
KEY_FEATURE_NOT_INSTALLED:
Feature key that indicates that the voice may need to download additional data to be fully functional. The download will be triggered by calling TextToSpeech#setVoice(Voice) or TextToSpeech#setLanguage(Locale). Until download is complete, each synthesis request will either report TextToSpeech#ERROR_NOT_INSTALLED_YET error, or use a different voice to synthesize the request.

You could verify that the language is available, I think this always come true, then try to use the setLanguage, which should trigger the download, and then use KEY_FEATURE_NOT_INSTALLED in a loop with some delay to check when the language has been downloaded. That's just a guess, and I might try out that in the future to give a feedback to the user.